# How to setup automatic classpath update in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am looking for a way to setup automatic resolution in my eclipse project. Lets say all of my jar files are situated in `%PROJECT_HOME%/lib` folder. So, every time a new jar is added, this should be added to the project classpath also. I am thinking for some way so whenever a jar file is copied in the target location, this new jar will be also available in project classpath.

A similar feature is as in web projects. When a jar file is added in `WEB-INF/lib`folder, this is autometicaly added to web app library.

What are the options, I do have?

Comment: You can write an Eclipse plugin...

Answer (score 1):

Take your time and learn to use [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/), or a similar build tool. It will take a lot of work, but it will do even more work for you automatically in the long run.

Comment: I do use `maven` for my personal works. But in my work place this is not a option.